# how to make process repeat specific times using fork() in C

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to make function that does 'receiver' work(as parent process) and 'transmitter' work(as child process).

I wrote 'pid_t got_pid = wait(NULL); ' at parent process so that 'transmitter'(child process) work does its job before 'receiver' work.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>


void foo(num){
  static int fd[2]; 
  static pid_t pid;

  pipe(fd); 
  pid=fork(); 
  
  if (pid<0){
    printf("fork error\n");
    return;
  }

  //parent process
  else if(pid>0){ 
    pid_t got_pid = wait(NULL); 
    printf("receiver\n");
  }
  
  //child process 
  else{ 
    printf("transmitter\n");
  }
}

int main(){
  foo(0); 
  foo(1);
  foo(2);
  foo(3);
}
```

I called foo() 4 times at main() function and I was expecting to see results like

```
transmitter 
receiver 
transmitter
receiver 
transmitter 
receiver 
transmitter 
receiver
```

but i get results like this.
[image: result]

I understand that wait() function makes parent process waits for child process to finish,

How should I write code to make child process and parent process do their job for only the times that I called in main?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include that in your question. This helps you find the error yourself and it is also required. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the first call to `makePipe` the child writes `transmitter`, does the rest of its job, and **returns to main**. The next call to `makePipe` is executed by *both* original process *and* the child. Ditto for the remaining calls. That's why you have that many transmitters (and receivers too).

As for

> why functions that I called in main() starts faster than remaining parent process

the answer is "just because". Unless you do explicit synchronization, nothing is guaranteed order-wise. You may encounter any sequence of events.